# Spring cloud streams test failing after adding AOP advice that executes around the target method

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-test, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud streams application with a stream listener consuming events from an input channel. Everything run smoothly until I added an AOP advice to log the execution of the handling method (between others in the application). After that, a test started to fail with the following error:

> org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking com.acme.fx.exchangerate.store.infrastructure.entrypoint.messaging.ExchangeRateStoreStreamListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9795881e#handle[1 args]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The mapped handler method class 'com.acme.fx.exchangerate.store.infrastructure.entrypoint.messaging.ExchangeRateStoreStreamListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9795881e$MockitoMock$1733324661' is not an instance of the actual endpoint bean class 'com.acme.fx.exchangerate.store.infrastructure.entrypoint.messaging.ExchangeRateStoreStreamListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9795881e$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a2d55ce'. If the endpoint requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.
>   HandlerMethod details: 
>   ...

Sink definition:

The application code is as follows:

```
public interface ExchangeRateStoreStreamSink {
        String NEWEXCHANGERATE="new-exchange-rate";

        @Input(NEWEXCHANGERATE)
        SubscribableChannel newExchangeRate();
}
```

Stream Listener with the annotated method:

```
@EnableBinding(ExchangeRateStoreStreamSink.class)
public class ExchangeRateStoreStreamListener {
    private CommandBus commandBus;

    @Autowired
    public ExchangeRateStoreStreamListener(CommandBus commandBus) {
        this.commandBus = commandBus;
    }

    @Loggable(operationName="ExchangeRateConsumption")
    @StreamListener(ExchangeRateStoreStreamSink.NEWEXCHANGERATE)
    public void handle(NewExchangeRateMessage newExchangeRateMessage) {
        AddExchangeRateCommand addExchangeRateCommand = new AddExchangeRateCommand(newExchangeRateMessage.from,
                newExchangeRateMessage.to, newExchangeRateMessage.amount, newExchangeRateMessage.date);
        commandBus.dispatch(addExchangeRateCommand);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class ExchangeRateStoreStreamListenerTest {
    @Autowired
    private ExchangeRateStoreStreamSink streamSink;

    @SpyBean
    private ExchangeRateStoreStreamListener streamListener;


    @Test
    public void test() {
        SubscribableChannel input = streamSink.newExchangeRate();
        NewExchangeRateMessage exchangeRateMessage = NewExchangeRateMessageFactory.aNewExchangeRateMessage();
        input.send(new GenericMessage<>(exchangeRateMessage));

        verify(streamListener).handle(any(NewExchangeRateMessage.class));
    }
}
```

AOP Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    private static final String API_DOMAIN = "fx";

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(loggable) && execution(* *(..))", argNames = "loggable")
    public void loggableMethod(Loggable loggable) { }

    @Around(value = "loggableMethod(loggable)", argNames = "pjp,loggable")
    public Object logAccess(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Loggable loggable) throws Throwable {
        final Signature signature = pjp.getSignature();

        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(signature.getDeclaringType());

        logger.info( "api_domain={} _operation={} _message=\"Start operation\"",
                API_DOMAIN, loggable.operationName());
        try {
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (DomainError domainError) {
            // Some logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is more than welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the StreamListener is already a proxy. There is too much to explain and would probably be a good subject to do a blog. . . 
Anyway, I am glad though you have described the actual problem you're trying to solve which could be solved with a much simpler approach and that is by introducing `ChannelInterceptor` - which essentially acts as an Around advice for your message handler invocation.
Basically here is an example:

```
@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor 
public ChannelInterceptor channelInterceptor() {
    return new ChannelInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> msg, MessageChannel mc) {
            System.out.println("Before send to channel: " + mc);
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterSendCompletion(Message<?> msg, MessageChannel mc, boolean bln, Exception excptn) {
            System.out.println("After send completion to channel: " + mc);
        }

        @Override
        public void postSend(Message<?> msg, MessageChannel mc, boolean bln) {
            System.out.println("After send to channel: " + mc);
        }

    };
}
```

. . . and here is the output it would produce:

```
Before send to channel: input
Before send to channel: integrationFlowCreator.channel#0
===> SOME LOG MESSAGE INSIDE YOUR CODE 
After send to channel: integrationFlowCreator.channel#0
After send completion to channel: integrationFlowCreator.channel#0
After send to channel: input
After send completion to channel: input
```

You simply declare it in your configuration and you should be fine to go. It will be applied to all channels so you (with logic) monitor only the once you want.
Please refer to Javadoc for `GlobalChannelInterceptor` for more details.
Hope that helps

Comment: If you need to restrict that interceptor bean to the particular channel(s), you need to use a `patterns` attribute of the `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` annotation. See its Javadocs for more info.